# Street view plotted in maps.google.com is not same when plotting it from google map developer api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using the google developer api to plot street view map using the user input(address text). But the map view shown in our application is not same as the view shown in maps.google.com when we provide the same address in maps.google.com.

Steps used in the code:
1. Getting the lang and lat from geocoder api by passing the address.
2. Creating Street view panaroma by setting the lan and lat(received from step1), pitch, heading and zoom(by default we are setting pitch and heading to 0).

Points observed :
1. The property located in the streetview is same in both the case(in the Application and maps.google.com)
2. only the point of view varies(pitch, heading).

How to identify the default properties used in maps.google.com to use the same in the code?

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps StreetView from Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384664/google-maps-streetview-from-address)

Comment: Thanks!. it helped me to resolve the issue.