# Automatically show street view map when inputting an address

Tags: google-maps

I want to put in a street address, and have it programatically determine the coordinates and heading for the purposes of generating a street view map.  instantstreetview.com does this, so I know it can be done.  From the docs:

```
function initialize() {
  var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
```

Problem is, I don't know the heading of the address I want.  Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps StreetView from Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384664/google-maps-streetview-from-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into getting the `LatLng` from the [`StreetViewLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/street-view-service#StreetViewLocation) of the `StreetViewPanorama` rendered to compute the heading using the [`computeHeading()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/geometry#spherical.computeHeading) in the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) in the Javascript API.

Take a look at [this sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cucezajivu/edit?html,output). I've created two Street View divs with the lat/lngs of two addresses across the street from each other. Notice that, regardless of the lat/lng, the same pano is returned, but there is no heading information, so the view is the same:

[image: Two addresses one view]

Now, look at this [this modified JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qateqinuma/edit?html,output). After computing the heading based on the StreetViewLocation.latLng of the panorama and lat/lng of the addresses passed into [`StreetViewService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/street-view-service) and using that as the `pov` for the panoramas, the correct Street View imagery is shown for each address:

[image: two addresses two views]

The pertinent code:

```
var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(37.435292,-122.129517);
var svs = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

svs.getPanorama({location: ll, preference: 'nearest'}, function(data, status){
        var pos = data.location.latLng;
        var head = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pos, ll);
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('street-view'),
        {
          pano: data.location.pano,
          pov: {heading: head, pitch:0}
        });
     });
```

EDIT: Adding [another simple JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pizoziyeda/edit?html,output) showing the use of the [`Geocoder`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/geocoder) to get the `LatLng` for the addresses: Pertinent code:

```
var ll;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var svs = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

geocoder.geocode({address: "757 Moreno Ave Palo Alto, CA"}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    ll = results[0].geometry.location;
    svs.getPanorama({location: ll, preference: 'nearest'}, function(data, status){
      var pos = data.location.latLng;    
      var head = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pos, ll);
      panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('street-view'),
      {
        pano: data.location.pano,
        pov: {heading: head, pitch:0}
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @preston, not sure why SO is so full of DBs who downvoted a perfectly useful question, but your answer is exactly what i needed.

Comment: actually, i jumped the gun @preston, i don't see how to convert the input of an address, your code starts with lat/lng.  I need to start with "742 Moreno Ave Palo Alto, CA" and have it render a streetview map.