# combining google street view with places search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

For a project I'm currently working on, I'm looking to incorporate both elements of Google places to search with google street view, essentially forcing the location (after searching) to view as street/pano.

Google has a pretty solid 'basic' version but I can't seem to force it to use street view. Any insight would be awesome.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

https://www.instantstreetview.com/ - Seems to do a pretty good job of it, but I can't seem to find any documentation regarding both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the code from the [SearchBox example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), with the [StreetView example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple), should give you a first cut.

Probably more what you are looking for would be to combine the answer to this related question: [Facing the targeted building with Google StreetView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495948/facing-the-targeted-building-with-google-streetview), with the [SearchBox example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tnvgx8o9/3)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
var panorama;
var clickedMarker;

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place, index) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        clickedMarker = this;
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.getPosition(), 50, processSVData);
      });

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[0], 'click');

  });
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"));
    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    var camera = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: "camera"
    });
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, clickedMarker.getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "heading:" + heading + "<br>" +
      "location: " + clickedMarker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" +
      "camera:" + data.location.latLng.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";


    // alert(data.location.latLng+":"+myLatLng+":"+heading);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: heading,
      pitch: 0,
      zoom: 1
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    alert("Street View data not found for this location.");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```