# How to get POINT OF VIEW of specific Place using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places, google-street-view

I want to use Google Places Autocomplete - Per Session, with Place Details included, and when an user clicks on an item, display a Google Map StreetView with the Place.

The way I was trying to do was: when a user clicks on an autocomplete-list, I use `getPlace()` function for getting `geometry.coordinates` (lat and long), and initialize Google Map Street View with that information.

The problem is the start point of view of Google Map Street View, that is random.

Do you know how can I solve it? I think I can't get that information with Place Details. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: related question: [Facing the targeted building with Google StreetView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495948/facing-the-targeted-building-with-google-streetview)

Comment: related question: [Request main road / curbside StreetView panoramas instead of back alleys from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176327/request-main-road-curbside-streetview-panoramas-instead-of-back-alleys-from-ap)

Answer (score 2):

From the Places API, get the place coordinates.

> Example: **Belgian Embassy, Paris** returns `48.87501200000001, 2.2944579999999632`

Now use these coordinates to get Street View:

[image]

Obviously, **it doesn't show the Belgian Embassy**.

At the time the Panorama Service returns the data, you can get its *real* coordinates, in this case `48.87519271414293, 2.294281201461672` which as you can see is not exactly the same than the place coordinates.

Using the Geometry Library, you can compute the heading between the panorama coordinates and your place coordinates.

`let heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(StreetViewCoords, PlaceCoords);`

This will get you a heading.

Now before showing the panorama, set its heading:

```
streetView.setPov({
  heading: heading,
  pitch: 0
});
```

Street View is now heading to the Belgian Embassy:

[image]

Proof of concept below:

```js
var map;
var panorama;
var panoramaService;
var streetView;
var placeCoords;

function initialize() {

  placeCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(48.87501200000001, 2.2944579999999632);

  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: placeCoords,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  var panoramaOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
  };

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);

  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  streetView = map.getStreetView();
  runPanoramaService();
}

function runPanoramaService() {
  panoramaService.getPanoramaByLocation(placeCoords,
    100,

    function(streetViewPanoramaData, streetViewStatus) {
      if (streetViewStatus == "OK") {

        let heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng, placeCoords);

        streetView.setPosition(streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng);

        streetView.setPov({
          heading: heading,
          pitch: 0
        });

        streetView.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 80px;
}

#pano {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initialize">
</script>
```